# .NET User Roles Design- Granting Access

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I am using .NET Web Api and had a design question.  I have 50 of what is called a "planning unit". I want the managers of this units to be able to grant access to other users so they can read data from this units. The only design that comes to my mind for accomplishing this is to create 1 new user role for each planning unit and allow a manager to add a user to that role(Planning Unit 1,Planning Unit 2, etc).

I am sure there is a better way. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you think of a claims-based system instead of role-based? In such a system, your roles would also be so-called "claims". For your question about granting access, what would you think of adding a claim per unit instead, since its not really what roles are designed for. For example a claim with key "unit" and as value the unit's ID. What do you think?